# SQL Descending value incorrect

Tags: php, sql, dashboard

I am creating a dashboard project for a game and in my table the highscore is showing 900 however there are values that is higher than that, how is that possible.

here is the sample screenshot of my prototype web site
[Sample Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ13Q.png)

and here is the query I use
for high score to show

```
SELECT max( highscore ) as max FROM users
```

for the table

```
SELECT id,username, highscore FROM users ORDER BY highscore DESC
```

Here is the format of my table

```
Ranking || Highscore ||
1       ||  945      ||
2       ||  905      ||
3       ||  823      ||
4       ||  3457     ||
5       ||  2680     ||
```

I want the highest value (3457) to be on the rank one but the 945 always goes to the top and the order is broken i hope the provided sample image helps I am really bad at explaining things online

thank you and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: You are not giving us enough information to work with.  My first thought I would think is that MAX is being used on strings by accident as 9 is higher than 2.  Thats what my logic would state.

Comment: oh my bad i really am bad at explaining things online

Comment: run the sql statement `desc users;` and post output. (edit your question and add it, formatted, don't put it in a comment)

Comment: Show us your database schema.

Comment: Im sorry for the late reply I already edited my question im sorry again

Comment: Ok I think I got it sorry for the inconvinience thank you @Fallenreaper and thank you guys for the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you declared the column Highscore like varchar? If you try this query:

```
SELECT id,
       username, 
       highscore 
FROM users 
ORDER BY CAST(highscore as int) DESC
```

And

```
SELECT max( CAST(highscore as int) ) as max 
FROM users
```

What outputs if you cast it to integer?